# Can I use same secret_file.json for multiple servers for google API?

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api

I am not sure about this. Can I have the same secret file having client_id generated from google developer console for multiple servers like dev, stage?

When running the script with the same key on stage, I got a link to allow and enter verification code, would it unauthenticate the process running on dev if I do so?

Comment: Yes you can, **BUT** it is a best practice to use different  clientIDs for dev, production or other servers. This is also discussed in the related [issue post - Multiple apps using same clientid](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3/issues/2662).

Comment: Thanks :) I was afraid it might un-authenticate from another server.